Union over variadic template parameters
Given a variadic list of types Ts..., can we create a union object that holds exactly a union of these types (and no extra data)?
Certainly this is possible with std::variant. However, the critical design piece here is that for each instance of this union, I will always know what type it holds, and so it seems wasteful to waste the space on the tag of std::variant.
To elaborate more on the use case here, I'm trying to make this work, which is a tuple that A) can be accessed by element and B) can be moved from.

Thank your for sharing your observation. What is your question?

If each instance is always a specific type, and you always know what type that is, then why use a union at all? What is the actual problem you think such a union will solve? This sounds like a possible XY Problem.

If you know your types you don't need a variant.

Something along these lines, perhaps.

@RemyLebeau apologies - use case is clarified a little bit.

@IgorTandetnik with such an impl, how might we efficiently be able to retrieve the elements (in O(1))

@Thornsider3 your use case is not clear. Can you please provide actual code that you are having trouble with?

With -O2, the get call gets competely optimized away

@RemyLebeau: at least as I read it, a container of things. At any given time, all the things in the container will be the same type, so no need to store the type individually for each.

@JerryCoffin still not clear why that would need to be a container of unions, though.

@RemyLebeau: Not sure it really does need to be. For that matter, I'm not sure my guess is correct. Was kind of hoping the OP would confirm or deny it...

@JerryCoffin Presented a snippet of what I'm trying to do (with some of the annoying TMP details excluded for readability), so that this is more clear. Thanks for the feedback.

Yes, obviously it is possible because std::variant is implementable.
However, the core language unfortunately doesn't provide any nice syntax sugar for it.
Essentially you need to do something like
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct variadic_union {
    union {
        T t;
        variadic_union<Ts...> ts;
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct variadic_union<T> {
    T t;
};

and then similarly define recursive member functions to access the contents.
Because the linear nesting may negatively affect compile times, if you have many element types, it may be better to instead split the types in each layer by half to get something like a binary tree nesting instead.
The nesting is not a problem at runtime though. Even if e.g. a get method needs to recursively call down to other get member functions, the resulting call chain will be optimized into a single call to the base get via inlining. Access to the elements will be possible in constant time, except in a debug compile mode or if your compiler doesn't do a good job implementing inlining. This kind of inlining is essential to make C++ abstractions work. Without it a lot of C++ constructs that ought to be "zero-cost abstractions" won't be.

There is also a much simpler solution for a variant-like type that doesn't require a union at all:
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct tagless_variant {
    alignas(Ts...) std::byte buffer[std::max({sizeof(Ts)...})];
};

Here you can then use placement-new and explicit destructor calls to implement creation/destruction of elements of any of the types. To retrieve an element you would need to return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<U*>(buffer)) where U is the stored type.
The problem with this solution is that it can't be made constexpr-friendly.

In any case, both solutions will require you to make certain assumptions on the type. In particular, because the class itself doesn't know the stored type, it can't call the correct destructor automatically. So either the user will be required to explicitly reset the object or the class must only allow types with trivial destructor or the destructors are simply skipped, which can easily cause resource leaks.
If you intent the type to be copyable or movable, then you will need to similarly restrict yourself to trivially-copyable types.

Thank you for your answer. I want to know more about why the second solution works. When we cast buffer to U*, the location of the resulting pointer certainly depends on U*, so how does C++ know to "cast" it to the correct location? I've also seen this come up with a struct w/ multiple inheritance that can have its this pointer be static casted to any of its parent types, and I wanted to know how this is possible.

@Thornsider3 static_cast, used to cast pointers in inheritance hierarchies, and reinterpret_cast are completely different. They are not interchangeable and in most situations only one of them is correct and won't have undefined behavior. reinterpret_cast from a pointer (in this case after array-to-pointer decay &buffer[0] with type std::byte*) to any pointer type U* suitably aligned for type U, assured here with alignas(Ts...), produces another pointer with the same pointer value, but type U*.

@Thornsider3 This means reinterpret_cast<U*>(buffer) is an expression of type U* with exactly the same value as &buffer[0], i.e. it points to the first element of the array. In particular the address, as part of the pointer value, is also unchanged. Because there is a mismatch between the type of the pointer and the type of the object that the pointer actually points to, using the result directly is almost always undefined behavior.

@Thornsider3 However, if you previously created a U object at &buffer[0], which then is nested within the buffer, and that U object is still in its lifetime, then you can use std::launder to change the pointer value from pointing to the beginning of the buffer array to a pointer pointing to the U object which is placed at the same address.

@Thornsider3 If you haven't created a U object with e.g. new(static_cast<void*>(buffer)) U; inside the buffer or if you created another object of different type in it afterwards, then the call to std::launder will have undefined behavior. Also note that the buffer must obviously have sufficient size, in addition to alignment, otherwise the placement-new will have undefined behavior. Also, the buffer must be of type std::byte or unsigned char, since these are the only types which are specified to be able to provide storage for other objects.

@Thornsider3 static_cast between pointer types does something completely different and is, in contrast to reinterpret_cast, able to modify the address of the pointer value, e.g. when casting from a derived class type to a base class type which is offset into derived class storage.

@Thornsider3 "When we cast buffer to U*, the location of the resulting pointer certainly depends on U*": No, because you would have needed to place the U object beforehand exactly at &buffer[0], it is impossible that an address offset is needed and reinterpret_cast will never add or subtract any address offset.. Any other usage of this construct, e.g. placing a derived class object and then trying to obtain a pointer to the base class from buffer instead, would have, just like in the union case, undefined behavior.

So if I'm understanding correctly, *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<U*>(buffer)) only works if U is our first type, and if we want to access the third type, that we know exists and we know holds V, we would need *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<V*>(&buffer[2]))?

@Thornsider3 No, not at all. Your get function would look simply like template<typename U> U& get() { return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<U*>(buffer)); } and your emplace function like template<typename U, typename... Args> void emplace(Args&&... args) { ::new(static_cast<void*>(buffer)) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } or simpler template<typename U, typename... Args> void emplace(Args&&... args) { std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<U*>(buffer), std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

@Thornsider3 Any of the possible types in Ts... would be located at the start address of the array, just like any of the Ts... types in the union case would be located at the start address of the union. The array as an object itself is not important. It is only used for its storage to have enough storage available in the tagless_variant object to store any of the Ts... types that it could possibly need to store.
